# Bibliography in chronological order but with alphabetical abbreviation

Tags: bibtex

I want my bibliography to be in chronological order but I also want it to have the alphabetical abbreviation. An example to clarify: if my sources are

- Smith, Title1, 1999
- Johns, Title2, 2023
- Taylor, Title3, 2012

Then I want my bibliography to look like:

- [Smi99] Smith, Title1, 1999
- [Tay12] Taylor, Title3, 2012
- [Joh23] Johns, Title2, 2023

Using the alphabetical mode yields (I don't want this)

- [Joh23] Johns, Title2, 2023
- [Smi99] Smith, Title1, 1999
- [Tay12] Taylor, Title3, 2012

and the chronological mode yields (I don't want this neither)

- [Smith, 1999] Smith, Title1, 1999
- [Taylor, 2012] Taylor, Title3, 2012
- [Johns, 2023] Johns, Title2, 2023

I have no clue how to do that and I didn't find any post about someone asking to do this. Any help will be greatly appreciated !

I have a file biblio.bib with my references. My main.tex file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\input{settings}
\input{macro}
\begin{document}
    \bibliographystyle{chronological}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliography{biblio.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: give your readers a chance to find a reference and don't invent a new order. If you use an alphabetic label then order them alphabetically.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Your answer is not really helpful. I won't have readers, it's for my own use, and chronological order is what best suits what I want to do, but the way the documents are referenced with chronological order is awful, hence my question.

Comment: I didn't answer -- you didn't provide an example or any code to allow a sensible answer-- I only commented about the unusual label.

Comment: I provided a very precise example of what I want... And I'm not trying to "invent a new order", I just want the chronological order with the kind of labels of the alphabetical mode. Now if there is no possibility to do so, it's ok, I'm just asking, I think it's the purpose of this forum... ^^'

Comment: the answer depends on your code, e.g. how you use biblatex (if you use it at all).

Comment: Sure, thank you. I'll had my code to my main post, it doesn't display well here.

Comment: well then you are not using biblatex (and your tag is wrong) and changing the sorting requires to find a style which implements your wishes. I doubt that exists but perhaps you can create one with custom-bib/makebst: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib

Comment: Right, sorry for the confusion between bibtex and biblatex... :/ I changed the tag. Thanks for the pointer.